# Permission Denied on Select tables after giving Select permission to new user in Azure Postgres SQL single server database

Tags: postgresql, azure-postgresql

I have Azure postgresql single server database which I need to give read permission to a newly created user.

CREATE USER "test@hostName" PASSWORD 'XXXX';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "test" TO "test@hostName";

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER pgadmin
IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT   ON TABLES TO  "test@hostName" ;

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
WHERE grantee = 'test@hostName';

This is the result
[image]

But when this user executes a select query Permission Denied message appear and not allowed to select. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Default privileges work on new tables created after this statement, not the current tables. You have to grant select to all tables as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To assign permission to newly created user in Azure PostgreSQL follow below procedure:**

- First create a new database and a user in azure Postgres SQL and assign connect permission to it on newly created database.

```sql
--create a new database.
CREATE DATABASE newdb;
--create a new user.
CREATE USER newuser PASSWORD '<StrongPassword!>';
--grant new user to connect databse.
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE newdb TO newuser;
```

- Then go to new database with current login and grant select to all tables on `public` schema to the new user with following command.

```sql
--to switch the database with current login
\c test
--Grant select on table with ath following schema
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schemaname TO newuser;
```

[image]

- After this login with that user in Postgres SQL and select the table

```sql
select * from tablename;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could get the access. after granting the access, I create a view. but the user cannot read the view. The view is created after adding read permission to the user. 

I did ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER  pgadmin
IN SCHEMA public

GRANT SELECT  ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
   TO readuser;

Comment: Any idea how to do that?